# merge querysets in django

Tags: python, django, merge, django-queryset

I have in `models.py`:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    players1 = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name='games1')
    players2 = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name='games2')

    def get_all_players(self):
        return list(itertools.chain(self.players1.all(), self.players2.all()))
```

How can I write same `get_all_players` method, but return `QuerySet`, not `list`?

P.S. I know that there is | operator:

```
def get_all_players(self):
    return self.players1.all() | self.players2.all()
```

But it works in a very strange way. Result of this function contains more players than there are in players1 + players2 (result contains repeats of some players)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
# On the top of the file:
from django.db.models import Q

# Game instance method:
def get_all_players(self):
    return Player.objects.filter(Q(games1__pk=self.pk) | Q(games2__pk=self.pk))
```

`Q` is described in details here: [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that `games1` in `Q` will iterate all games. Tell me, why do you use `games1__pk=self.pk` instead of `games1=self`? Are there any advantages in this way?

Comment: @imkost: I am just used to it. I believe `games1=self` may be implicitly translated to `games1__pk=self.pk` (if it gives you the same result). Having `__` in the argument name also makes it clear that there are some `JOIN`s involved in the query.

Answer (score 12):

For a perhaps more semantically clear solution:

```
def get_all_players(self):
    return (self.players1.all() | self.players2.all()).distinct()
```

Comment: This is definitely the more clean solution.